# Working with PhD student instead of professor

Tags: research-undergraduate

I'm currently an undergrad, and our university has a research program that I'm taking part in. I was hoping to get the chance to work with a professor, but in reality I just worked with the professor's PhD student. In fact, throughout the whole semester, I've only met the professor once at the start of the semester. I have other friends who joined the same program under other professors, and they also shared the same experience.

Is this normal for undergrad research programs? I'm just concerned because for example if I need recommendation letters in the future, I don't think the professor knows me that well (and I don't think the PhD student is allowed to write one?)

Comment: One of several already answered: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/123300/72855